# How to get folder path using electron

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, electron

I am very new to the electron. Can anyone suggest me how to get a local folder's relative path using the electron? JavaScript does not have that capability.

[image]

I have a Choose File button(see snapshot), so my question is that when I select a folder and click on the open button then it should return a whole directory path.

Comment: anyone have answer??

Comment: Did you use [showOpenDialog](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.2/api/dialog/#methods)?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As @phuongle pointed out in the comments you want to use `showOpenDialog()`. Something like this:

```
var remote = require('remote');
var dialog = remote.require('electron').dialog;

var path = dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ['openDirectory']
});
```

UPDATE: If the above isn't working for your current Electron version, you should try more modern importing:

```
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
```

In addition, in order to use `remote`, you need to set `enableRemoteModule` when creating your window in your main process:

```
const myWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
});
```

Comment: just FYI `const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;` isn't using module imports, its object destructuring.

Answer (score 16):

Following the official [IPC tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) worked for me

**main process:**

```
import {dialog, ipcMain} from 'electron'
function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({/*Your electron window boilerplate*/})
  ipcMain.handle('dialog:openDirectory', async () => {
    const { canceled, filePaths } = await dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
      properties: ['openDirectory']
    })
    if (canceled) {
      return
    } else {
      return filePaths[0]
    }
  })
}
```

**preload script:**

```
import {contextBridge, ipcRenderer} from 'electron'

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI', {
  selectFolder: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog:openDirectory')
})
```

**Now you can call the selectFolder method from your application code and get the user input.**

```
window.myAPI.selectFolder().then(result=>{/* Do something with the folder path*/})
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update for recent versions of electron (works with 25.3.0) and ES6 import**

- First thing : import electron remote
  `npm install --save @electron/remote`
- Then in your main process (where you create your window) :

```
import * as remoteMain from '@electron/remote/main';
// ...
remoteMain.initialize();

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      plugins: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      webSecurity: false
      // ...
    }
  });

  remoteMain.enable(win.webContents);

  //...
}
```

- Finally the function I use to log the file path in my component :

```
import * as remote from '@electron/remote';
// ...
async function getDir() {
  const showDialog = await remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ['openDirectory']
  });
  // Do things with showDialog
  console.log(showDialog.filePaths) // logs the directory path.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Electron we can select the directory by specifying simple input element with type="file" and webkitdirectory attribute'. 
    `<input id="myFile" type="file" webkitdirectory />` and we can get the directory full path with the path property of File object `document.getElementById("myFile").files[0].path`

Comment: Note: If you're doing this in React, you have to write `webkitdirectory="true"` instead. Just tripped me up.

Comment: This doesn't work. Show a working example to prove me wrong. You need to be able to get the full path of the directory including files too.

Comment: @AlexCory  Note: this solution is specific to Electron environment.

Comment: I tried this solution in electron and instead of giving me the directory name it gave me a window path. Something like `C\...`. Maybe it's because I put all the browser's webkit attributes on the input `webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple`. Also, this solution still doesn't give the absolute path to the directory.

Comment: when i use webkitdirectory with React it returns all the files path contained in the directory rather than the directory path itself (can take some time when selecting a folder with a lot of files...)

Comment: `webkitdirectory` works fine for selecting files, but not for folders.  If you use `webkitdirectory` to select a folder, what actually happens is that you select all files in the folder and in subfolders.  If there are no files, the selection is empty and you cannot even determine which folder you selected.

Answer (score 0):

You would use Node's [`path.relative`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to) for that.

Comment: sorry, i am not looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was simply using all in lowercase, with a value `true` as string in my react component. No extra configuration was required.

Like so:

```
<input
    id="path-picker"
    type="file"
    webkitdirectory="true"
/>
```

**Edit**

It turns out that, as mentioned by @cbartondock, it will recursively look for files in the directory, which is not good!

I ended up using the required electron remote's dialog.

Comment: Doing this leads to a recursive search of the directory chosen, which is a massive waste of time if all you are interested in is the path to the directory itself.